# Can not install any apps due to syntax error in grub.cfg file

Tags: boot, grub2, software-installation

I ran into this error while using "sudo update-grub"

```
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-48-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-48-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-44-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-44-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows Recovery Environment on /dev/sda1
error: out of memory.
error: syntax error.
error: Incorrect command.
error: syntax error.
Syntax error at line 329
Syntax errors are detected in generated GRUB config file.
Ensure that there are no errors in /etc/default/grub
and /etc/grub.d/* files or please file a bug report with
/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new file attached.
```

The grub.cfg.new file can be found here: https://pastebin.com/pgiczCXZ
. Now because of this error I can't install anything new. I'm so lost at where is wrong.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks for reading!
**Updated** : I managed to fix by using @nobody method. If you have same issues, please reconsider it!

Comment: Not the correcr file: `Ensure that there are no errors in /etc/default/grub
and /etc/grub.d/* files`. Question: what did you change in either `/etc/default/grub` or in the files in `/etc/grub.d/* files`?

Comment: You've provided no OS/release details; but your provided paste shows only *unsupported* kernels (5.13 was used by 20.04 using HWE package before upgrade to 5.15, or used by 21.10 which is now EOL).  What OS/release are you using as paste shows outdated & unsupported package(s).

Comment: @guiverc I currently use Ubuntu 20.04 version.

Comment: @Rinzwind Well I actually have no idea because I didn't intentionally changed those. Here's the link to the files you might need: https://pastebin.com/gymQ9BYm and  https://pastebin.com/WsuEshkw. That's all I have in those directories.

Comment: `sudo chmod -x /etc/grub.d/41_custom` and `sudo chmod +x /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober` then try `sudo update-grub` againn please.

Comment: @nobody When I did what you meant, instead of getting error at line 329, it changed to line 321. Here's the new file of grub.cfg.new: https://pastebin.com/E76aQjjk. Thanks anyway

Comment: [Updated] I managed to fix it by using your command with not 41_custom but 40_custom and repeated two other commands. Thanks for your suggestion @nobody.